Flask-sqlalchemy session is not fetching data when creating under a app.cli.command()
engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
Base.metadata.bind = engineDBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

@app.cli.command("generate_task_notifications")
def createTaskNotification(): # Run scheduled job for creating task
    statuses.print('starting jobs')
    generate_task_notifications()
    print('scheduled jobs executed at '+ str(datetime.now()))
    return

def generate_task_notifications():
    session = DBSession()
    upcoming_days_upto = int(session.query(SystemConfig).filter(SystemConfig.Key == e_SysConfig.UpcomingDay.Key).first().Value)
    session.close()
    return upcoming_days_upto

If I run the same as an API endpoint then it's working fine but when I am trying to use the same as flask command then upcoming_days_upto is giving error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Value'.
Though data is there in the database, I have checked the same using beekeeper studio as I am accomodating the sqlite database.
I tried shifting the session creation code inside the cli command function but I was unlucky and when try to run the same as an API endpoint then it's working fine.

Could you include the command you run when you are executing this via CLI?

Sure, inside the directory where wsgi.py file exists, I am firing -
flask generate_task_notifications

Thankyou so much for help!
Somehow I came to know that it was creating another database file and considering the same in use. So I have made modifications in a way that actual database file located at the place where both the approaches i.e. API endpoint and CLI command can access.
/project_parent/init.py:
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///parent_project/Database.db'
/project_parent/controllers/cronJob.py:
This is where I am trying to access and it's giving below error -
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file

This would suggest that the result of your query is None. Therefore, Value is not a property, since the None type has no property named Value.
You should conditionally execute:
def generate_task_notifications():
    session = DBSession()
    res = session.query(SystemConfig).filter(SystemConfig.Key == e_SysConfig.UpcomingDay.Key).first()
    if res is not None:
        upcoming_days_upto = int(res.Value)
    session.close()
    return upcoming_days_upto

This does avoid the error, but in reality might not be a solution to your problem, depending on what that is. It could be an incorrectly formatted query, but without the DB Models and the filtering logic, we can not diagnose that.

Yes correct, it will query None. But there's a database file that exists and having data that it should query ideally.
